# Repeated code, need help creating a function formating and creating new columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, date, formatting

I have some different dataframes containing date and need to create and format the data.
Step 1. Convert dataframe$date as date. Step 2&3. Create new columns with week and year. Step 4&5 convert week and year to numeric.
Since I need to do this multiple times, I would like to create a function out of it.

```
dataframe$date <- as.Date(dataframe$date, "%Y-%m-%d")
dataframe$week <- strftime(dataframe$date, format = "%V")
dataframe$year <- strftime(dataframe$date, format = "%Y")
dataframe$week <- as.numeric(dataframe$week,as.numeric)
dataframe$year <- as.numeric(dataframe$year,as.numeric)
```

My attempt:

```
format.dataframe <- function(a) {

  paste(a, $date, sep="") <- as.Date(paste(a, $date, sep=""), "%Y-%m-%d")
  paste(a, $week, sep="") <- strftime(paste(a, $date, sep=""), format = "%V")
  paste(a, $year, sep="") <- strftime(paste(a, $date, sep=""), format = "%Y")
}
```

So a should be the name of the dataframe I want to format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` in base R :

```
format.dataframe <- function(a) {
  transform(a, date = as.Date(date, "%Y-%m-%d"), 
               week = as.numeric(strftime(date, format = "%V")),
               year = as.numeric(strftime(date, format = "%Y")))
}

a <- format.dataframe(a)
```

Or with `mutate` in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

format.dataframe <- function(a) {
  a %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%Y-%m-%d"), 
           week = as.numeric(strftime(date, format = "%V")),
           year = as.numeric(strftime(date, format = "%Y")))
}

a <- format.dataframe(a)
```